# Append is adding the sum instead of adding to a list python

Tags: python, list, append

I tried to append but whenever I would try to print it down in the `main()`, it would print the average but added up.

```
def letter_grade(test_score):
    if int(test_score) >= 90:
        grade = 'A'
    elif int(test_score) >= 80:
        grade = 'B'
    elif int(test_score) >= 70:
        grade = 'C'
    elif int(test_score) >= 60:
        grade = 'D'
    else:
        grade = 'F'
    return grade


def calc_avg_grade(test_score):
    average = []
    func_sum = sum(test_score)
    avg = func_sum/5.00
    average.append(avg)
    average.reverse()
    return average


def main():
    grades = []
    i = 0
    outfile = open('studentgrades.txt', 'w')
    while i < 4:
        name = input("Enter the student name: ")
        for x in range(5):
            score = float(input("Enter number grade: "))
            grades.append(score)
            gradle = letter_grade(score)
            print(str(score) + ' - ' + gradle)
        avg_grade = calc_avg_grade(grades)
        avgg = avg_grade
        print(name + "'s average grade is: " + str(avgg))
        outfile.write(name + ', ' + str(avg_grade) + "\n")
    txtcontents = outfile.read()
    print(txtcontents)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The part where it runs the append that I have the problem at is:
`print(name + "'s average grade is: " + str(avgg))`
This is def main().

Comment: What "problem" are you facing?

Comment: Separately, where are you increasing the value of `i`? Your `while` loop never exits.

Comment: i think quarmrana answered my question. With the while loop, do i add i += 1 to the end of the while loop to make it end?

Comment: Your variable, `average` is a local variable to the function `avg_grade`. Your function will always return a `list` with one value, no matter how many times you call the function. You should initialize it in `main` and pass it in as an argument. (You shouldn't need to return the list if you're only modifying it with its methods.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not reinitialising `grades`:

```py
def main():
    # grades = []  # Not Here!
    i = 0
    outfile = open('studentgrades.txt', 'w')
    while i < 4:
        name = input("Enter the student name: ")
        grades = []  # here instead
        for x in range(5):
            score = float(input("Enter number grade: "))
            grades.append(score)
            gradle = letter_grade(score)
            print(str(score) + ' - ' + gradle)
        avg_grade = calc_avg_grade(grades)
        avgg = avg_grade
        print(name + "'s average grade is: " + str(avgg))
        outfile.write(name + ', ' + str(avg_grade) + "\n")
    txtcontents = outfile.read()
    print(txtcontents)
```

This way you get a new empty `grades` for each student and `avg_grade` will be the right average for that student.